# Google Tag Manager: "Quantity" in Ecommerce Measurement purchase: weird behavior with for-loop

Tags: for-loop, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'll try to be as precise as possible. First of all, this is my dataLayer:

```js
var prods = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
  prods.push({
    'name': myVar[i][roomRateCode],
    'id': myVar[i][roomCode],
    'price': myVar[i][roomTotal] / myVar[i][numberOfNights],
    'category': myVar[i][rateCode],
    'quantity': myVar[i][numberOfNights],
  });

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'reservationCompleted',  
    'ecommerce': {
      'currencyCode': myVar[i][currency],
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {
          'id': myVar[i][reservationNumber],
          'affiliation': myVar[i][hotelName],
          'revenue': myVar[i][totalRevenue],
          'tax': myVar[i][taxes],
          },
        'products': prods
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Consider, this is a hotel. So I want to track rooms, rates, number of nights, etc in the Purchase method. All ecommerce information are stored into a javascript object (myVar).

The reason why I set it up this way, is because users may book multiple rooms in a single booking process; when doing so, the system will generate as many maVar objects as the number of rooms booked. So, basically, with the above for-loop I first count how many myVar's are there in the page and store all pairs values into the "prods" array, before pushing into the dataLayer.

Now, as you can see I use the command "Quantity" to count the number of nights booked. So a reservation for a room for 2 nights, I send 2.
All good when it comes to 1-room-bookings, however I notices something weird when it comes to multiple-room bookings.
Long story short, Quantity value is doubled in the Google Analytics console, although even looking in the Preview mode of GTM everything looks fine.

Here is the test I just made. A reservation for 2 rooms, 2 nights each.

Here a few screenshots:

This is the event "reservationCompleted" firing for the first room:
[image]
and for the second room:
[image]
And this is the number of Quantity in GA:
[image]
Why in GA I have quantity=4 each rather than 2?

--------------------[UPDATE]--------------------------

I made a test for a reservation of 2 rooms, 3 nights. Results are actually the same, so in the GA is showing 6 nights each, rather than 3. Here's myVar object, I had to fake it a little bit just to hide sensitive data.

```js
var myVar = [{
  "numberOfRooms": 1,
  "rooms": {
    "arrivalDate": "2018-10-24",
    "departureDate": "2018-10-27",
    "category": "WW\/My Hotel\/MyHotelCode",
    "chainCode": "WW",
    "childAges": null,
    "hotelCode": "HADXBBON",
    "hotelName": "My Hotel",
    "hotelStars": 5,
    "hotelCurrency": "AED",
    "leadDays": "63",
    "numberOfNights": 3,
    "numberOfAdults": 1,
    "numberOfChildren": 0,
    "rateDescription": "Flexible Rate",
    "rateCode": "DR",
    "rateCurrency": "AED",
    "ratePerNight": "835.44",
    "rateType": "Flexible Rate",
    "reservationNumber": "125731076",
    "roomCode": "B1K",
    "roomDescription": "My First Room",
    "roomRateCode": "IB1KDR",
    "roomTotal": "2506.32",
    "totalTaxes": "509.32",
  }
}, {
  "numberOfRooms": 1,
  "rooms": {
    "arrivalDate": "2018-10-24",
    "departureDate": "2018-10-27",
    "category": "WW\/My Hotel\/MyHotelCode",
    "chainCode": "WW",
    "childAges": null,
    "hotelCode": "HADXBBON",
    "hotelName": "My Hotel",
    "hotelStars": 5,
    "hotelCurrency": "AED",
    "leadDays": "63",
    "numberOfNights": 3,
    "numberOfAdults": 1,
    "numberOfChildren": 0,
    "rateDescription": "Flexible Rate",
    "rateCode": "DR",
    "rateCurrency": "AED",
    "ratePerNight": "835.44",
    "rateType": "Flexible Rate",
    "reservationNumber": "125731077",
    "roomCode": "A2T",
    "roomDescription": "My Second Room",
    "roomRateCode": "IA2TDR",
    "roomTotal": "2965.70",
    "totalTaxes": "593.70",
  }
}];
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also thought of simply dividing the number of nights by the length of the loop (myVar[i][numberOfRooms] / myVar.length), but then in this last case it will assign a Quantity of 1.5 which is rounded by Google to 2, so not a valid option.

Comment: can you share the myVar structure? also can you share what happens if you do 3 nights 2 rooms?

Comment: @AnkDasCo Thanks for your reply, above I just published the updated information.

Comment: The code shows that you are counting the total quantity of rooms that are booked in one transaction. Like 3 rooms and 2 nights gives us 6 = total. 
Your query - You want to make it to 3 for the booked rooms even though it is for 2 nights. I would recommend taking a different route, use `variants` to segment it. What happens if I book 1st room for 3 nights and 2nd room for 4 nights. What would show up in `quantities` as per your requirements?